# How can I work out if Itunes:Keep iTunes Folder Organized is set programmatically on Windows

Tags: java, com, itunes

How can I work out if **Itunes:Preferences:Advanced:Keep iTunes Folder Organized** is set programmatically on Windows, my Java application that interacts with iTunes needs to know this.

Unfortunately neither the iTunes xml File or the Itunes COM API seem to provide this information, I assume it because they are preferences stored somewhere else but how can I find out whether enabled or not, I also need to know this for **Copy files to iTunes Media Folder when adding to library**

**Update:**
Nothing in registry but Ive found a preferences file

C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Apple Computer\iTunes

however it seems to be encrypted/encoded, I dont know how to read the values

**Update 2:**

Saved a copy of file, changed the value of Copy files to iTunes Media Folder when adding to library and compared and have picked up a change

```
<key>Documents:132</key>
<data>
AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAV09SQjQAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAADUXX4fAc2UWH8BAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
</data>
```

versus

```
<key>Documents:132</key>
<data>
AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAV09SQjQAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAACwf6jgsOrUhX8BAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=
</data>
```

but as you can see difficult to spot the difference, and Id be concerned if I hacked this valkue it could break between iTunes versions, is there do way to decode this file ?

**Update 3**

I found that [Apache Commons Configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/user_guide.html) supports Apples plist format as Xml format http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/plist/XMLPropertyListConfiguration.html but not unfortunately the binary format used here.

I wrote this code that listed all the keys, and then tried to decode the location property as I know this just contains a single base64 encoder filepath.

```
public File getITunesXMLFile()
    {
        String homedir = System.getProperty("user.home");

        File prefsFile = new File(homedir,"AppData/Roaming/Apple Computer/iTunes/iTunesPrefs.xml");
        try
        {
            XMLPropertyListConfiguration xpc = new XMLPropertyListConfiguration(prefsFile);
            xpc.load();
            Iterator<String> keys = xpc.getKeys();
            while(keys.hasNext())
            {
                String nextKey = keys.next();
                System.out.println(nextKey+":"+xpc.getProperty(nextKey).getClass());
            }
            ArrayList location = (ArrayList)xpc.getProperty("User Preferences.iTunes Library XML Location:1");
            System.out.println("Location:"+location.get(0).getClass());
            System.out.println("Location:"+location.get(1).getClass());

            System.out.println("Location1:"+ new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(location.get(0).toString()));
            System.out.println("Location2:"+ new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(location.get(1).toString()));
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MainWindow.logger.log(Level.SEVERE,"Unable to open iTunes Prefs file:"+prefsFile.getName(),ex);
        }
        File xmlFile = new File(homedir + "/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml");
        if (!xmlFile.exists())
        {
            return null;
        }
        return xmlFile;
    }
```

but unfortunately didn't work as the data is returned as an ArrayList of a class of type [B which makes no sense to me, its not a valid name for a class.

Output is

```
EQ Preferences.EQPresets:129:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.Documents:132:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.Gracenote User ID:1:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.Music Store:1:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.Pairing Preferences:301:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.Preferences:130:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.Radio Tuner Categories:131:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.Touch Remote Preferences:400:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.iTunes Library XML Location:1:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.iTunes..exe:AAC Encoder:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.iTunes..exe:iTunes Classic Visualiser:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.license-agreements.EA0962:class java.util.ArrayList
User Preferences.storefront:class java.util.ArrayList
Location:class [B
Location:class [B
Location1:[B@58a7a
Location2:[B@2893bb6f
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

and also found this issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONFIGURATION-262

**Update 4**

Found a library that already supports binary code.google.com/p/plist looks hopeful

**Update 5**

I have managed to use this library to decode the Xml file location as follows (Base64 class from Apache Commons Codec 1.8)

```
public File getITunesXMLFile()
    {
        System.getProperties().list(System.out);
        String homedir = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File prefsFile = new File(homedir,"AppData/Roaming/Apple Computer/iTunes/iTunesPrefs.xml");
        File xmlFile;
        try
        {
            NSDictionary rootDict = (NSDictionary) PropertyListParser.parse(prefsFile);
            NSDictionary userPrefs = (NSDictionary) rootDict.objectForKey("User Preferences");
            if(userPrefs!=null)
            {
                NSData iTunesLocation = (NSData) userPrefs.objectForKey("iTunes Library XML Location:1");
                if(iTunesLocation!=null)
                {
                    String base64 = iTunesLocation.getBase64EncodedData();
                    String filepath = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(base64),"UTF-16LE");
                    xmlFile = new File(filepath);
                    System.out.println(filepath+":File Exists:"+xmlFile.exists());
                    if (xmlFile.exists())
                    {
                        return xmlFile;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //Use default then
            xmlFile = new File(homedir + "/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml");
            if (xmlFile.exists())
            {
                return xmlFile;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**Update 6**

I tried to do this for the data I was really interested in, I am able to extract the base64encoded data from the Documents:132 key, but unfortunately trying to decode this base64encoding doesnt really get me anywhere, maybe I'll just have to look for differences in the base64encoded data when flags are enabled/disabled.

```
 public boolean isiTunesCopyFolderToMediaFolder()
    {
        String homedir = System.getProperty("user.home");
        File prefsFile = new File(homedir,"AppData/Roaming/Apple Computer/iTunes/iTunesPrefs.xml");
        try
        {
            NSDictionary rootDict = (NSDictionary) PropertyListParser.parse(prefsFile);
            NSDictionary userPrefs = (NSDictionary) rootDict.objectForKey("User Preferences");
            if(userPrefs!=null)
            {
                NSData options = (NSData) userPrefs.objectForKey("Documents:132");
                if(options!=null)
                {
                    String base64 = options.getBase64EncodedData();
                    System.out.println("optionBase54Data:"+base64);
                    String optionData = new String(Base64.decodeBase64(base64));
                    System.out.println("optionData:"+optionData);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
    }
```

outputs mostly spaces (AAAA's)

optionBase54Data:AQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAV09SQjQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAADUXX4fAc2UWH8BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=

plus embedded in the output

WORB4

and

�]~͔X

An example of the iTunes preferences file can be found here

http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/scratch/iTunesPrefs.xml

Comment: Did you take a look in the registry?

Comment: I have now, nothing in registry but I think Ive found the preferences

Comment: A hack: save a copy of the file, change the preference setting (uncheck the "Keep organized" box), save a second copy, do a diff... maybe you can see the difference?

Comment: thx, that has helped a bit

Comment: That looks like base64 encoded binary. I realize that's not much help - but `AAA` = `0x00` and `AQA` = `0x10`. I don't think that's completely coincidental. Unfortunately this is probably a binary image of a specific structure... and I don't know what the structure is. I can help you turn it into binary format if you like. Not sure it will really help.

Comment: Thanks there is details of the format at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CONFIGURATION-262 but I dont know C code

Comment: Ah, found a library that already supports binary http://code.google.com/p/plist/

Comment: .. but doesn't seem able to extract the value I actually want

Comment: Could you post a copy of the xml file you are trying to parse somewhere?

Comment: Hi, okay http://www.jthink.net/jaikoz/scratch/iTunesPrefs.xml

Comment: I looked at that file, but so far I'm scratching my head like you... Really enjoy seeing you updating the question as you learn more!

Comment: How about looking for the "Automatically Add to iTunes" folder ?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the iTunesPrefs.xml with the setting on and off then compared the differences.

With it checked (true)

Base64 encoding: AAIAAAAAAAEAAAAGAQAA/////wEAAHoAAP////8EAEYAbABhAHQAAAAAAAAA

Hex value: 02 01 06 01 01 **7a** 04 46 6c 61 74

With it not checked (false)

Base64 encoding: AAIAAAAAAAEAAAAGAQAA/////wEAAHsAAP////8EAEYAbABhAHQAAAAAAAAA

Hex value: 02 01 06 01 01 **7b** 04 46 6c 61 74

This is contained under Preferences:130, how these values are being stored I don't know, maybe you can find something on this. Consider using the command line to find the differences in a file, `diff` for linux or `fc` for windows.

I know this isn't an answer but this wont fit in a comment.